# How to save a view automatically in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have some views for an mvc application.we want to give save functionality on a particular view which will caputre everything from that view and save it in a folder on server eithier in pdf or html file type.

Save functionality should be called when user clicks on button on view.How can we achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you say, you want collect all data from View or you want to save exactly how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

First your view must be linked to your data model.
To manage the sync between both either you use binding mechanism if your framework supports it or you implement a observer/observable pattern.
Next you have to write an event handler to respond to the save event triggered by the save button.
This event handler must call the save functionality.
To be more precise you should tell which language/framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, the target of my functionality is,  we have an external portal which was built on MVC which uses CRM as backend. We will be having some views in Portal which needs to be send to the Microsoft HealthVault  as a PDF or an Html file.  We achieved creating a HTML file for the view. now our intention is to send the saved file to healthvault from portal.

Comment: We are using Knockout for binding the data.

Comment: Knockout is a JS framework therefore the binding feature it provides is between your frontend view and the view.  But I guess the PDF generation and sending must be performed on the backend.  So when the save event is triggered then a call to the backend must be performed (REST API?) to synchronize the backend model and call the PDF conversion and sending.